# Group array of object into shorter array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to make this

```
const arr = [
    {
        "name": "mac"
    },
    {
        "group": "others",
        "name": "lenovo"
    },
    {
        "group": "others",
        "name": "samsung"
    }
]
```

into this:

```
 [
   {
     name: 'mac',
   },
   {
     name: 'others',
     group: [
       {
         name: 'lenovo',
       },
       {
         name: 'samsung',
       },
     ],
   }
 ]
```

I tried to use normal forEach loop but it didn't turn out well:

```
let final = []
const result = arr.forEach(o => {
    if(o.group) {
        group = []
        group.push({
            name: o.name
        })
        final.push(group)
    } else {
        final.push(o)
    }
});
```

Not sure if reduce might help? before I try lodash groupBy I want to use just pure js to try to make it.

Comment: Using the same key for different purposes looks like really bad object design.

Comment: @connexo it's just the demo data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer will work for you.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "mac",
  },
  {
    group: "others",
    name: "lenovo",
  },
  {
    group: "others",
    name: "samsung",
  },
];

const temp = [];
arr.forEach((e) => {
  if (!e.group) {
    temp.push(e);
  } else {
    const index = temp.findIndex((ele) => ele.name === e.group);
    if (index === -1) {
      obj = {
        name: e.group,
        group: [{ name: e.name }],
      };
      temp.push(obj)
    } else {
      temp[index].group.push({ name: e.name });
    }
  }
});

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: check my output, your output is wrong

Comment: please check your question, what you want ? @JennyLe

Comment: you want above output in your question or below ?

Comment: you need to read my question again, your output is wrong. this is the output `[{"name":"mac"},{"name":"others","group":[{"name":"lenovo"},{"name":"samsung"}]}]` run your own script.

Comment: so please check your question first, what you want from into this

Comment: if you want to above output so please set this output in I want to content

Comment: please check now, i have edited my answer, hope it will help you

Comment: it worked! findIndex is interesting!

Comment: add vote or give useful answer if it's worked

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating and pushing `group array` in `final` again and again u should just `push` group in the end of foreach
like this--

```
let final = []
let group = []
const result = arr.forEach(o => {
    if(o.group) {
        
        group.push({
            name: o.name
        })
    } else {
        final.push(o)
    }
})
final.push({name: "others", group})
```

Comment: and also `const result` is not neccessary in `forEach`

Comment: you hardcoded "others" which is incorrect.

Comment: oh kk sry i thought he only wanted others array i will correct it Thanx :D